# How does this snippet work with the buffer? Java

Tags: java, buffer

So basically this code is supposed to keep asking "Please insert a valid number" until an integer is introduced through the keyboard. It works just fine, I'm just curious as to how it actually does what it does.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please insert the number of lives.");
while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
    input.next();
    System.out.println("Please insert a valid number.");
}
numberOfLives = input.nextInt();
```

In my head it would make more sense to put the numberOfLives = input.nextInt(); line inside of the while loop. This is basically what I'm understanding from this snippet once it reaches the while loop:

1. Check condition in while, if input scanner variable doesn't have an int value, do the following
2. Discard what is in the input scanner variable
3. Print out the valid number message

Obviously this isn't how it goes, else this snippet wouldn't work. I'm thinking maybe each time it checks the condition, the actual !input.hasNextInt() opens up the buffer again for input and THEN checks what's inside, but I have no clue.

Sorry if I'm not using the terms correctly, pretty now to all of this stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like an iterator, scanner will always point to the element before the stream starts. i.e. if the list starts with position 0, scanner will point to -1st position. next() will advance the scanner and return the element present at location.
In this code, we are checking if the next element is integer. If it is not, why to advance the scanner?